# Rounding corner for UIRectCornerTopRight doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm using the following code to attempt to round the top right corner of a UIView:

```
UIBezierPath* rounded = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer* shape = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
[shape setPath:rounded.CGPath];

view.layer.mask = shape;
```

When I run the code, the UIView just doesn't round the right corner:

[image]

However when I change from UIRectCornerTopRight to UIRectCornerTopLeft, it seems to work:

[image]

Comment: Is there any other view on top of your textfield that might be clipping it? Have you tried other corners? Where are you calling that code?

Comment: In the first image you posted, there is something going on with the top right corner of the gray area.  Is that something else, or is that being caused by this same code?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  Moving my code to viewDidLayoutSubviews as in @beyowulf's answer did not work for me.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you have this code in viewDidLoad or somewhere before the layout engine has adjusted your textfield's frame, thus the masking path is for a longer frame. Try moving your code to viewDidLayoutSubviews.